# Using `QUrl` for file-paths feeds to `std::fstream`

Tags: c++, qt, url

Using `QFileDialog`, for allowing the user to browses files (for opening), it returns the list of files as `QUrl`

```
QFileDialog dialog;
dialog.setFileMode(QFileDialog::ExistingFile);
dialog.setAcceptMode(QFileDialog::AcceptOpen);
if (!dialog.exec() || dialog.selectedUrls().size()==0) return;
 
QUrl url = dialog.selectedUrls()[0];
```

After this, the provided url is in the following format:

> file:///C:/Users/[...]/test.xml
>
> file:///home/[...]/test.xml

This does not seem to works for `std::ifstream` so I am trying to (un)normalize the path. For this, I tried the following:

```
QUrl nUrl = url.adjusted(QUrl::RemoveScheme | QUrl::RemovePassword | QUrl::RemoveUserInfo |
               QUrl::RemovePort| QUrl::RemoveAuthority | QUrl::RemoveQuery |
               QUrl::RemoveFragment | QUrl::StripTrailingSlash |
               QUrl::NormalizePathSegments);
```

Which return a path in the following format:

> /C:/Users/[...]/test.xml
>
> /home/[...]/test.xml

The first slash works on Linux, but not on Windows. And if I remove the first slash, it would works on Windows, but not on Linux.

The quesiton is:

**How to convert `QUrl` reliably to a format which is accepted by `std::fstream`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use QUrl::toLocalPath instead of QUrl::adjusted